# iOS app on Emulator with Robovm: how can I display the log in console?

Tags: eclipse, logging, libgdx, ios-simulator, robovm

I am using LibGDX 1.4.1 and Eclipse.
I can build and run my iOS app on an emulator thanks to the great plugin RoboVM (v. 1.0 alpha 4).
However, I have been trying to display a simple log to the console with no success.
I have tried the following:

```
private static final Logger logger = new Logger("mylog", Application.LOG_INFO);

Foundation.log("foundation:TEST1"); //that is org.robovm.apple.foundation.Foundation;
Gdx.app.log("mylog", "Gdx:TEST1"); 
logger.debug("log.debug:TEST1");
System.out.print("print:TEST1");
System.out.println("println:TEST1");
System.err.println("errprint:TEST1");
```

I have tried to display any of these in the following Eclipse views:

- Console RoboVM
- Console iOS Simulator App
- Error log
- Debug

I know that this code is run because I do manage to get the following working properly in the app when I add it next to the log code:

```
UIAlertView uiAlert = new UIAlertView();
uiAlert.setTitle("Title");
uiAlert.setMessage("TEST1");
uiAlert.addButton("OK");
uiAlert.setCancelButtonIndex(0);
uiAlert.show();
```

Naturally I first checked the RoboVM console. It logs everything up to the launch of the app, so what I get displayed always ends with:

```
12/5/14 11:00:32 AM: [ INFO] Launch done
```

After that, I trigger the events in-app that are supposed to trigger the log in code, and nothing is displayed.

What am I missing? Maybe the log is displayed in a Eclipse view I am not cheking? Else, how can I display log in my RoboVM console?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a bug in RoboVM 1.0.0 alpha 04 when launching apps in an iOS 8.1 simulator. This has been fixed in the next release which is due to be released next week. In the meantime you can install an iOS 8.0 simulator via Xcode and use that for testing and you should see the print outs.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nicklas, I'll check for the update every day this week :) Thanks for all your work in RoboVM, except a few little things it does wonders. Keep up the great job!

Comment: Unfortunately updating RoboVm doesn't seem to change anything, I am still having the same problem. Is there any setting or configuration that I have missed? In what view of Eclipse should I see the logs?